# How to formatted a PHP float number like "00.00" pattern?

Tags: php, design-patterns, format

I have a student's marks between (0 to 20), i want to formatted as a float like this pattern "**00.00**".

example:

- 12.5    ==> **12.50**
- 3.45    ==> **03.45**
- 12.4689 ==> **12.46**
- 0.752   ==> **00.75**

this some code witch i try, but no result as i expected!

```
$output= round($number,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);

$output= sprintf('%00.02f',$number);

$output= str_pad($number,5,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

**EDIT: (SOLVED)**

i use this *one line* **solution** it worked perfectly, thanks to @AkshayHegde:

```
$output=sprintf("%05.2f",floor($number*100)/100);
```

Comment: `12.4689` is not `12.47` ?

Comment: Exactly, for this one 12.4689 i need to show  12.46  not 12.47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Online Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/59e10d92157850731a881a68f26dcda4240ae9c5)

```
[akshay@db1 tmp]$ cat test.php 
<?php

$arr = [12.5, 3.45, 12.4689, 0.752];
foreach($arr as $a){
    printf("original:%7s ==> rounded:%05.2f  ==> without-rounded:%05.2f\n",$a,$a, floor($a*100)/100);
}
```

Output:

```
[akshay@db1 tmp]$ php test.php 
original:   12.5 ==> rounded:12.50  ==> without-rounded:12.50
original:   3.45 ==> rounded:03.45  ==> without-rounded:03.45
original:12.4689 ==> rounded:12.47  ==> without-rounded:12.46
original:  0.752 ==> rounded:00.75  ==> without-rounded:00.75
```

> Use [floor()](https://www.php.net/floor) - Round fractions down
>
> With `%05.2f` for value `3.45` it prints `03.45` that is 5 chars long.

Comment: it worked perfectly, Thank you a lot. in one line: $output=sprintf("%05.2f",floor($number*100)/100);

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `number_format()` function:

```
<?php
    $number = '3';
    $output= round($number,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
    $output= sprintf('%00.02f',$number);
    $output= str_pad(number_format($number, 2),5,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo $output;
```

You can read more about [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: thank you for your response, i had try it, but not worked for me. what's about for this example: 3.45 ==> 03.45, i need a zero padding before 3

Comment: You need to use the `number_format` before the str_pad.

Comment: it worked for all my examples, except this one: (12.4689 i need to show 12.46 not 12.47 ) it's appear that  PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN don't work as i expected!! any idea please?

Comment: Why you need `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN` anyway??

Comment: PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN is for taking only two decimal digit. but it seem that this function number_format($number, 2) is overwrite it!

Comment: You don't need the `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN ` at all, try without it

Comment: Thankx for All, this one from @AkshayHegde is worked: $output=sprintf("%05.2f",floor($number*100)/100);

Comment: As I said you don't really need `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN`